# List all DB tables - JPA

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I want to list all the tables in my DB using Spring boot and `JPA`, I have created a `DataSource` configuration like - [configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle](https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/) and tried -

```
@Repository
public interface  TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Table, Long>{
    @Query("SELECT owner, table_name  FROM dba_tables")
    List<Table> findAllDB();
}
```

And my `Table` Entity -

```
@Entity
public class Table {
    String owner;
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

}
```

And got -

```
No identifier specified for entity: com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.repos.Table
```

So how do I query for DB tables names?
So far my main -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AwsFileUploadApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    TestRepo repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //https://wwwtest.plm.automation.siemens.com/subsadmin/app/products
        SpringApplication.run(AwsFileUploadApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource); //some value - ds init sucess
        List<Table> findAllDB = repo.findAllDB();
        System.out.println(findAllDB);
        }
    }
```

When removing @Entity from Table - `Not a managed type: class com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.repos.Table`.

Comment: You shouldn't have an entity for this: an entity is supposed to have an ID, and to be mapped to a database table. Instead, you should use a native, SQL query, returning tuples. You're currently defining a JPQL query, and JPQL doesn't use tables and columns, but entities and their properties.

Comment: Any entity must have an `@Id` attribute. Assuming name is unique then stick it on that.

Comment: @JBNizet - trying the native version, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I print all my tables and columns using JDBC:

```
    @Autowired
    protected DataSource dataSource;

    public void showTables() throws Exception {
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = metaData.getTables(null, null, null, new String[] { "TABLE" });
        while (tables.next()) {
            String tableName=tables.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            System.out.println(tableName);
            ResultSet columns = metaData.getColumns(null,  null,  tableName, "%");
            while (columns.next()) {
                String columnName=columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                System.out.println("\t" + columnName);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you look at the [getTables API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) you can see how to refine the search of tables.

Comment: How to get just the tables for one database or database schema? It even prints the sys_config of MySQL